# Getting Android SDK WebView and TabWidget to play nice

Tags: android, layout, webview, android-widget

I’m taking the **[HelloTabWidget](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)** Android example and trying two things:

- Moving the tabs to the bottom vs. the
  top (if that’s even desirable from an Android UI POV)
- Making each tab show a particular
  **WebView** in the space above

I’ve got this for a layout (high level):

```
<TabHost>
  <LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout>
      <WebView/>
      <WebView/>
      <WebView/>
      <WebView/>
      <WebView/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <TabWidget/>
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Everything has a width/height set to `fill_parent` except for the **TabWidget** which has its `layout_height` set to `wrap_content` (and the `layout_gravity` set to `bottom`).

First thing I noticed is that **WebView**s don’t show anything until all the parents have width/height set to `fill_parent`. However, once I do that, they fill the entire display, obscuring the **TabWidget**.

Is there some other trick to making these two views play nicely together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, tabs will not work at the bottom.

`TabHost` and `WebView` work fine together, though I do not have a current sample that demonstrates this.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean about the gravity=“bottom” not working out. Also, it doesn’t look correct with the tab direction. I moved it back to the top and … everything works! I didn’t even need any padding. I’ll look at your code sample as well. Thanks!!!

Comment: Actually, it's good to know that the LinearLayout avoids the padding issue. Once upon a time, I don't think that worked. Thanks!